# How to synchronize gulp from local to live website (server)

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend, web-frontend

Gulp setup is working fine for me in local.

But i want like if i change files in local then it will build and uploaded to live server automatically (minified css and js/compiled css/js).

I have tried [gulp-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync), [vinyl-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp) but couldn't succeed may be i don't know how to use above packages.

Here is a my gulp file.

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
    var useref = require('gulp-useref');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
    var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
    var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    var cache = require('gulp-cache');
    var del = require('del');
    var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

    // Development Tasks 
    // -----------------

    // Start browserSync server
    gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
      browserSync({
        server: {
          baseDir: 'app'
        }
      })
    })

    gulp.task('sass', function() {
      return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss and children dirs
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError)) // Passes it through a gulp-sass, log errors to console
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Outputs it in the css folder
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ // Reloading with Browser Sync
          stream: true
        }));
    })

    // Watchers
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
      gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
      gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    })

    // Optimization Tasks 
    // ------------------

    // Optimizing CSS and JavaScript 
    gulp.task('useref', function() {

      return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });

    // Optimizing Images 
    gulp.task('images', function() {
      return gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
        // Caching images that ran through imagemin
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
          interlaced: true,
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
    });

    // Copying fonts 
    gulp.task('fonts', function() {
      return gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
    })

    // Cleaning 
    gulp.task('clean', function() {
      return del.sync('dist').then(function(cb) {
        return cache.clearAll(cb);
      });
    })

    gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
      return del.sync(['dist/**/*', '!dist/images', '!dist/images/**/*']);
    });

    // Build Sequences
    // ---------------

    gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
      runSequence(['sass', 'browserSync'], 'watch',
        callback
      )
    })

    gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
      runSequence(
        'clean:dist',
        'sass',
        ['useref', 'images', 'fonts'],
        callback
      )
    })
```

And here is a my folder structure.

This is main folder

[image]

It's a development folder

[image]

And this one is production folder in which all files are build.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to provide with type of server are you using.
Most of the servers can run a script after a deploy. I personally suggest to use Heroku and have your code on Github.

Comment: i don't know for which script are you talking about. i just have FTP details in which i want to deploy.

Comment: are you sure that you want to store the login data to your server, in the repository? Every one that has access to that repo might read it.

Comment: Please provide what you have done with vinyl-ftp it seems straightforward to me what you have to do to establish an ftp connection. Give as any error output you have.

Comment: https://blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-sync-local-and-server-development-gulp this tutorial may work for you

Comment: @Thomas i have read blog in which username and password asking in cmd terminal

Comment: @JonathanMuszkat already tried this one not working for me. i will show you error asap.

Comment: @JonathanMuszkat  I have tried your suggestion it's not working for me here is error https://prnt.sc/h82xih

Comment: @MilanAgheda thats because you didn't enter the correct values here:
var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'hostname.com',
        user:     'user',
        password: 'password',
        parallel: 3,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );